# Keras: stop gradient after a certain layer

Tags: keras

Suppose you have a Keras NN model, how can you stop the gradient in the backpropagation after a certain layer?

---

I.e., if we have a model with two outputs:

```py
input_layer = Input(shape=(10,10,3))

x = Convolution2D(...)(input_layer)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = Flatten()(x)

x_1 = Dense(64)(x)
x_1 = Dense(32)(x_1)
x_1 = Dense(2)(x_1)

x_2 = Dense(64)(x)
x_2 = Dense(32)(x_2)
x_2 = Dense(2)(x_2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[x_1, x_2])
```

How can the gradient of output `x_1` be stopped after the `x_1 = Dense(64)(x)` layer, such that it doesn't get counted in for the weight update in the convolutional layer?

---

Based on the answer in [Stopping Gradient back prop through a particular layer in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546100/stopping-gradient-back-prop-through-a-particular-layer-in-keras), I'd have added a lambda layer before the `x_1` dense layer, but I'm not really sure:

```py
x_1 = Dense(64)(x)
x_1_stop_grad = Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))(x_1)
x_1 = Dense(32)(x_1)
x_1 = Dense(2)(x_1)
```

Do I have to add the lambda layer **before** or **after** the first dense `x_1` layer?

Comment: Do you want the parameters of convolution layer not get updated/trained at all?

Comment: They should get updated, but only based on the output ```x_2```. 
Hence, the gradient in the backprop of output ```x_1``` should only be used for updating the ```x_1``` dense layers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the gradient is flowing backwards through the network, you need to add the gradient stop layer directly after the layer, where no gradient should arrive.

I.e.

```
# weights in x should not be updated by gradients from x_1
x = Convolution2D(...)(input_layer) 
x_1_stop_grad = Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))(x)
x_1 = Dense(64)(x_1_stop_grad)
x_1 = Dense(32)(x_1)
...
```